# 0x8000ffff JavaScript runtime error Unexpected call to method or property access

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Every time when I try to run this code in visual studio I get the above error. I am not sure what is going on. I know it's question like this, but I did not see this error in the answered in the solutions to this problem. Can anyone help me with this?

```
// display the lightbox
function lightbox() {
    var insertContent = "<div id='chartCon'>Test</div>";
    // jQuery wrapper (optional, for compatibility only)
    (function ($) {

        // add lightbox/shadow <div/>'s if not previously added
        if ($('#lightbox').size() == 0) {
            var theLightbox = $('<div id="lightbox" class="highcharts-container"/>');
            var theShadow = $('<div id="lightbox-shadow"/>');
            $(theShadow).click(function (e) {
                closeLightbox();
            });
            $('body').append(theShadow);
            $('body').append(theLightbox);
            //$().keydown(function (e) {
            //    if (e.which == 27) {
            //        closeLightbox();
            //    }             
            //});
        }

        // remove any previously added content
        $('#lightbox').empty();

        // insert HTML content
        if (insertContent != null) {
            $('#lightbox').append(insertContent);
        }

        //create chart
        var chart = $('#ChartContainer').highcharts('StockChart');
        var annots = chart.exportData()
        window.chartwidth = $('#ChartContainer').width();
        //chart.destroy();
        window.chartops.series = window.seriesOptions;
        $('#lightbox').highcharts('StockChart', window.chartops);
        $('#lightbox').highcharts('StockChart').importData(annots);

        // move the lightbox to the current window top
        $('#lightbox').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());

        // display the lightbox
        $('#lightbox').show();
        $('#lightbox-shadow').show();

    })(jQuery); // end jQuery wrapper

}

// close the lightbox
function closeLightbox() {

    // jQuery wrapper (optional, for compatibility only)
    (function ($) {

        //export possibly changed annotations and reset chartwidth
        var chart = $('#lightbox').highcharts('StockChart');
        var annots = chart.exportData()

        $('#ChartContainer').highcharts('StockChart').removeAllAnnotations();
        $('#ChartContainer').highcharts('StockChart').importData(annots);
        window.chartwidth = $('#ChartContainer').width();

        // hide lightbox/shadow <div/>'s
        $('#lightbox').hide();
        $('#lightbox-shadow').hide();

        // remove contents of lightbox in case a video or other content is actively playing
        $('#lightbox').empty();

    })(jQuery); // end jQuery wrapper

}
```

Comment: ***sigh*** What line is the error reported on?

Comment: It's giving me an error in another file called minInput.blur();. If that helps, If not maybe I can try and show the other file where the error is?

Comment: @user3784911 yes in general showing code *relevant* to the error helps a bit more

Comment: var minInput = rangeSelector.minInput,
     maxInput = rangeSelector.maxInput;
    if (minInput) {
     minInput.blur();
    }
    if (maxInput) {
     maxInput.blur();
    }
   };

Comment: That is the section given me the error.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is the function giving me the error

```
init: function (chart) {

        var rangeSelector = this,
            options = chart.options.rangeSelector,
            buttonOptions = options.buttons || [].concat(rangeSelector.defaultButtons),
            selectedOption = options.selected,
            blurInputs = rangeSelector.blurInputs = function () {
                var minInput = rangeSelector.minInput,
                    maxInput = rangeSelector.maxInput;
                if (minInput) {
                    minInput.blur();
                }
                if (maxInput) {
                    maxInput.blur();
                }
            };
```